# Python iterators/ one liner for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

This may be obvious, but I'm stuck as to whether I can use an iterator/one liner to achieve the following:

```
TEAMS = [u'New Zealand', u'USA']
dict = {}
```

How can I write:

```
for team in TEAMS:
    dict[team] = u'Rugby'
```

as an iterator, for example:

```
 (dict[team] = u'Rugby' for team in TEAMS) # Or perhaps
 [dict[team] for team in TEAMS] = u'Rugby
```

Can it be done, where do the parentheses need to be placed?

Required output:

```
dict = {u'New Zealand': u'Rugby', u'USA': u'Rugby'}
```

I know there are lots of questions related to iterators in python, so I apologize if this has an answer, I have tried looking and couldn't find a good answer to this particular issue.

Comment: If the value is an immutable object then you can simply do: `dict.fromkeys(TEAMS, u'Rugby')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension. Take a look below:

```
TEAMS = [u'New Zealand', u'USA']
d = {team: 'Rugby' for team in TEAMS}
```

Comment: you might want to rename your variable to a non built-in type

Comment: done. just provided the same name as the author had.

Answer (score 1):

use dict fromkeys method.
Also, not recommended to use keyword dict as var name, change to d instead

```
TEAMS = [u'New Zealand', u'USA']
d = {}.fromkeys(TEAMS, u'Rugby')
# d = {u'New Zealand': u'Rugby', u'USA': u'Rugby'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for team in TEAMS:
    dict.update({team: u'Rugby'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TEAMS = [u'New Zealand', u'USA']    
dict(zip(TEAMS, ['Rugby'] * 2))
```