# Java one liner for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505423/python-iterators-one-liner-for-loop), someone made a one-liner `for` loop in Python.

Another example is this:

```
someList = [f(i) for i in range(16)]
```

which would be a one-liner for this code:

```
someList = []
for i in range(16):
    someList.append(f(i))
```

or, in Java:

```
int[] someList = {}
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    someList = append(someList, f(i));
}
```

such that `f` is some function that will return an integer.

Now, is there an equivalent one-liner in Java?

> Note: Currently, I am using Processing, which is similar to Java, so, any code written in Java might be usable in Processing.

Comment: You can't append to an array in Java. Use an `ArrayList` or simply create array of correct size: `int[] someList = new int[16]` then do `someList[i] = f(i)` in the loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this in one line? I'd argue that you should favor readability over shortness. The `for` loop solution is easy to understand. Why not just stick with that?

Answer (score 19):

Java 8's [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to the rescue:

```
int[] someList = IntStream.range(0, 16).map(i -> f(i)).toArray();
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The original list is the OP is empty, and seems to just be defined as a necessity. The  original one-liner OP is trying to emulate creates a new list/array: `someList = [f(i) for i in range(16)]`